# How to dynamically add a button using html table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add dynamically button in html table.

I created a master page and another subpage.

On the sub page, I want to dynamically add a button in html table.

This is my code:

```
Button btnSend = new Button();
btnSend.ID = "btnSend";
btnSend.Text = "Send";
btnSend.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnSend_Click);
this.form1.Controls.Add(btnSend);
```

But I get an error:

> form1 is not accessible from sub page.

Please help me to dynamically add a button into the html table.

Comment: pls mark my answer as your solution if it helped you (mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use asp.net then you have no forms. So simply insert a button from the toolbox and set `buttonName.visible = true` or `false` as you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add dynamic controls to your sub page, then i suggest you to add a panel, and then simply use panel.controls.add(your button) and thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you create the HTML table on codebehind? If so, you may add the button there. 
If not, you may try putting a Literal there, and fill it with the code for an HTML button if needed.